# Definition of square function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

If we have two sets, the set of natural numbers and the set of integers and we relate each member of $\Bbb N $ to its squared value in $\Bbb Z$ then $f(x) = x^2$ and $\Bbb N $ is the domain of function and $\Bbb Z$ is the codomain. Is it okay to define the square function in this manner?

Comment: What you have written is a valid function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$. If you want to call it a square function, that would also be fine, thought it would beg the question "why "a" and not "the"", ie this is an example, not a general definition.

Comment: Yes. This defines a function with no ambiguity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I'm sorry Tobias, I'm not a native speaker, I may make mistakes in grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your definition is fine: $$f:\mathbb N \to \mathbb Z$$
$$f(x) = x^2\quad\text{i.e.,}\quad x\in \mathbb N \overset{\large f}{\longmapsto} x^2 \in \mathbb Z$$ is defined *everywhere* on $\mathbb N$, and is a well-defined function, pure and simple.

Note that the *image* of $f$ is $$\{x^2\mid x\in \mathbb N\} \subset \mathbb N \subset \mathbb Z$$ That is, the *image* of $f$ is a proper subset of the codomain you've defined for $f$, since $x^2 \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb N$ (and for all $x \in \mathbb Z$, if the domain were $\mathbb Z$). That's ***not*** a problem with your definition. That's just an observation.

Comment: I should sue you for plagiarism. But I'll upvote you instead.

Comment: @julien Oh!...I just saw your "no ambiguity" Yikes!

Comment: @julien I think you have a case.